# Postgresql no ideas to select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have 3 tables like this:

```
CREATE table materials
 (id serial primary key not null,
 name varchar(50) not null,
 unit varchar(10) not null default 'шт',
 price decimal(12, 2) not null check (price>0));

CREATE table warehouses 
(id serial primary key not null,
 lastname varchar(25) not null);

CREATE table materials_in_warehouses
 (id_warehouses integer references warehouses(id) on update cascade on delete cascade,
 id_materials integer references materials(id),
 unit varchar(15) default 'шт',
 count integer not null CHECK (count>0),
 lastdate date not null, 
primary key (id_warehouses, id_materials);
```

I need to select all materials with the price of > 200 , such that:
on each warehouse this material is available in an amount of > 100.

The problem is that the condition we have to fit all the warehouses with this material, not any one. I have no ideas.

For example, i have:

```
materials 
id     name     price    unit
---    ------   -----    -----
3      Silver   300      kg

warehouses
id     lastname   
----   --------- 
2      Forman
3      Tramp

materials_in_warehouses
id_materials     id_warehouses   count  lastdate
------------     -------------   -----  --------
3                3               300    2015-12-20
3                2               200    2015-12-20
```

...and i want to see Silver in my result, but if i add to table materials_in_warehouses where count was < 100, as a result, silver should not be.

This is my example query, but it is not suitable for the condition

```
select materials.name
  , materials.price
  , materials.unit 
from materials
  , materials_in_warehouses 
where price > 200 
 AND id = id_materials 
 AND count > 100;
```

Comment: Can you post any SELECT statement that you have tried?

Comment: @StingyJack
 select materials.name, materials.price, materials.unit from materials, materials_in_warehouses where price > 200 AND id = id_materials AND count > 100;
But it's don't work for each warehouse, only for one.

Comment: I added your query to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with subqueries like this:

First case, count > 100 at each warehouse

```
SELECT * FROM materials WHERE id IN (
    SELECT m.id FROM 
        materials_in_warehouses AS mw INNER JOIN 
        materials AS m ON (m.id = mw.id_materials) 
    WHERE 
        m.price > 200 AND 
        mw.count > 100
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouses)
);
```

Second case, sum of all warehouse count > 100

```
SELECT * FROM materials WHERE id IN (
    SELECT m.id FROM 
        materials_in_warehouses AS mw INNER JOIN 
        materials AS m ON (m.id = mw.id_materials) 
    WHERE 
        m.price > 200 
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING SUM(mw.count) > 100
);
```

OK, third case, all materials where price > 200 **AND** count in each warehouse > 100

```
SELECT m.* FROM 
    materials_in_warehouses AS mw INNER JOIN 
    materials AS m ON (m.id = mw.id_materials) 
WHERE 
    m.price > 200 AND 
    mw.count > 100
GROUP BY id
```

As simple as possible

Comment: No Results( 
I'm sorry , maybe I'm wrong to explain the task. I added in the description of an example of how it should work.

Comment: @Birthright, do you want all materials price > 200 and count > 100 at each warehouse **OR** price > 200 and sum of count of all warehouses > 100?

Comment: First. I have Silver, for example,  and four warehouses №1, №2, №3, №4. if price>200 -> if №1 and №2 and №3 and №4 have count >100 -> i want result of this material, else if one of four warehouse have count <=100, i don't want result of this material.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to firstly JOIN the tables and establish the relationships.

```
SELECT 
 w.lastname
 , m.name
 , m.price
 , miw.count
FROM materials m
 INNER JOIN materials_in_warehouses miw
   ON m.id = miw.id_materials
 INNER JOIN warehouses w
   ON w.id = miw.id_warehouses
```

From there, you can add where clauses to locate the data you wish.

```
WHERE m.price >= 200
  AND miw.count > 100
```

An ORDER would help as well, but only to view the results.

```
  ORDER BY w.lastname, m.name
```

If you are still missing records you expect to see at this point, its likely a data problem (you dont have warehouses defined in the MIW table, or materials are missing from the materials table).

EDIT: If you consider the data in the above question, and add change the MIW row for warehouse 2 to have a count of 50, then that row will be excluded. You will still see Silver listed in the results because it exists at warehouse 3 in the quantity you seek.

Comment: For example, in table materials i have: id = 3, name = 'Silver', price = 300, unit 'kg'. In table warehouses: id = 2, lastname= 'Forman', id = 3, lastname = 'Tramp', in table materials_in_warehouses: id_materials = 3, id_warehouses = 3, count =300, lastdate = '20.12.2015', unit= 'kg and id_materials = 3, id_warehouses = 2, count= 200, lastdate = '20.12.2015', unit 'kg' and i want to see Silver in my result, but if i add m_in_warehouses where count was < 100, As a result, silver should not be.

Comment: I added this data to the above question, but your data is what is at issue. .

Comment: Perhaps you should post an example (like the tables I used in your question) to describe the data you expect to see as a result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from materials 
inner join  materials_in_warehouses on materials.id = materials_in_warehouses.id_materials
where count>100 and price >200
```